# Запятая при уточнении

Tags: запятая

Будьте добры, подскажите мне, пожалуйста, как расставить запятые в предложении: Родился Шолыгин С.А в деревне Урюпино Казаковского сельского совета Новосельской волости Муромского уезда Владимирской губернии в семье крестьянина. Я бы перечисления отнесла к уточняющим обстоятельствам деревни Урюпина и поставила запятые. Но со мной не соглашаются. Подскажите

Comment: @Верьясова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Уточнение здесь будет чисто авторское,можно даже в скобки взять как пояснение
:" Родился Шолыгин С.А в деревне Урюпино (Казаковского сельского совета Новосельской волости Муромского уезда Владимирской губернии) в семье крестьянина.А в исходном виде запятые не нужны, это не однородные члены.

Comment: Но к уточняющим обстоятельствам относятся названия районов, областей, обозначающие местонахождение поселков, деревень. Здесь как раз такой случай.

Comment: Если бы это был почтовый адрес - да, там перечисляются данные для почтальона,так принято.А в обычном тексте - если данные по убыванию, то уточнение. Уточнение ведь от широкого к узкому. Если ж от узкого к широкому - не уточнение.Но как авторское возможно. А Вы привели пример по Розенталю, эти сведения несколько устарели, хотя и переписываются из справочника в справочник.В его же Справочнике по правописанию и литературной правке этого уже нет.

Comment: Понятно.Спасибо. Не успеешь за изменениями в русском языке.

Answer (score 1):

> ...в деревне Урюпино Казаковского
> сельского совета Новосельской волости
> Муромского уезда Владимирской губернии
> в семье крестьянина.

И всё же я бы воспользовался в этом случае справочником Розенталя **("Справочник по русскому языку. Пунктуация". 2-е изд., перераб., М., 2008)**:

> К уточняющим обстоятельствам относятся
> названия районов, областей и т. д.,
> обозначающие местонахождение поселков,
> деревень и т. д., а также указания в
> адресах:  *В деревне Уваровке,
>
> **Петровского района, Калужской области**,   состоялся праздник
> урожая; Посёлок Новые Горки,
> **Щёлковского района, Московской области,**   находится недалеко от
> станции Болшево; Москва, улица
> Плющиха, д. 38, кв. 2.*

**P.S.** Без запятых уж больно трудночитаемая конструкция получается.